# Mostrar primera palabra de un campo en SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, substring

Tengo la necesidad de sacar la **primera palabra** de un dato de la tabla.
He buscado información pero solo veo para sacar los caracteres que quieras.

```
<?php
    $usuario = $_SESSION['username'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['password'];

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Nombre, SUBSTRING(Nombre, 1,20) AS palabra, 
                              IdUsuario, Username, Password 
                              FROM Usuarios 
                              WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Password ='$pass'");
    mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
    if($res = $results->fetch_array()) {}

    ?>
```

Por ejemplo, en la columna `Nombre`, el registro contiene `Nombre Apellido 2Apellido`. Necesito extraer el `Nombre`.

Comment: ¿Caracteres o palabras? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de dato encontrado en el campo y el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Si po supuesto, modifico la pregunta

Comment: Busca la posición del primer espació y obten caracteres hasta el.

Comment: Vale, redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer uso de [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(cadena, delimitador, numero)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) para encontrar en la cadena la primera parte hasta el primer espacio en blanco:

```
<?php
/* Evitamos inyección SQL */
$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
/* Cambiamos a UTF-8 *ANTES* de hacer consultas SQL */
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$results = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT
    Nombre,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Nombre, ' ', 1) palabra,
    IdUsuario,
    Username,
    Password
  FROM Usuarios 
  WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Password ='$pass'
");
if($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
    /* Aquí se supone que haces lo necesario con $res['palabra'] */
}
?>
```

Lo que hace la función es dividir la cadena en porciones dadas por el delimitador y devuelve las `numero` primeras. Si `numero` es negativo, entonces devuelve las `numero` últimas. En el ejemplo uso `1` para que devuelva únicamente la primera parte (lo que haya antes del primer delimitador o espacio en blanco).

Puedes ver un [ejemplo en línea aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ffysQuVWpfxSkFy5Nxj2bS/0).

PD: He de advertirte que el código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string).

Comment: Modifico mi pregunta, porque lo hice tal cual pero con un As y no me imprime nada, gracias @OscarGarcia

Comment: No me deja editarla ya que la editaste tu;
("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Nombre, '', 1) AS palabra, 
                                  IdUsuario, Username, Password 
                                  FROM Usuarios 
                                  WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Password ='$pass'");

Comment: Prueba ahora con esta edición.

Comment: Ahora si!!! estupendo, quitaste el AS y además añadiste esto: $mysqli->real_escape_string

Comment: Sí, es MUY importante que uses consultas preparadas o bien esa función para evitar inyección SQL. Si quieres saber más del tema voy a hacer una nueva edición a mi respuesta a la página de la wikipedia y a un vídeo muy instructivo sobre el daño que se puede hacer a una página web si no se tiene cuidado con ese tema.

Comment: Lo tengo en cuenta @OscarGarcia, soy bastante novato en todo esto y es flipante todo lo que hay. Muchas gracias ya puse tu pregunta como buena.

Comment: Agregados los enlaces a la wikipedia y a mi vídeo. Espero que disfrutes con las pruebas que hago en él ;) y mucho ánimo aprendiendo y practicando :D

Answer (score 0):

usando un explode() de " " puedes obtener la primera palabra. ¡Saludos!

```
<?php
$usuario = $_SESSION['username'];
$pass = $_SESSION['password'];

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Nombre, SUBSTRING(Nombre, 1,20) AS palabra, 
                          IdUsuario, Username, Password 
                          FROM Usuarios 
                          WHERE Username='$usuario' AND Password ='$pass'");
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo explode(" ",$row['Nombre'])[0];
}

?>
```